# Using Markup via UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to support Apple's Markup of PDFs via `UIDocumentInteractionController` for files in my Documents folder on iPad. I want the documents edited in-place, so my app can load them again after the user is finished. I have set the `Info.plist` options for this, and the in-place editing does seem to work. Changes are saved to the same file.

When I bring up the `UIDocumentInteractionController` popover for the PDF, I am able to choose "Markup", which then shows the PDF ready for editing. I can edit it too. The problem is when I click "Done": I get a menu appear with the options "Save File To..." and "Delete PDF". No option just to close the editor or save.

The frustrating thing is, I can see via Finder that the file is actually edited in-place in the simulator, and is already saved when this menu appears. I just want the editor to disappear and not confuse the user. Ie I want "Done" to be "Done".

[image: The Done menu, which includes not direct "Close" or "Save" options.]

Perhaps related, and also annoying, is that while the markup editor is visible, there is an extra directory added to Documents called `(A Document Being Saved By <<My App Name>>)`, and that folder is completely empty the whole time. Removing the folder during editing does not change anything.

Anyone have an idea if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a way to have the Done button simply dismiss?

Answer (score 0):

In case others have this issue, I believe it is a bug in `UIDocumentInteractionController` in how it sets up the `QLPreviewController` it uses internally. If I proxy the delegate of the `QLPreviewController`, and return `.updateContents` from `previewController(_:editingModeFor:)`, it works as expected.

Here is my solution. The objective is simple enough, but actually capturing the private `QLPreviewController` was not easy, and I ended up using a polling timer. There may be a better way, but I couldn't find it.

```swift
import QuickLook

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    /// This wraps the original delegaet of the QLPreviewController,
    /// so we can return .updateContents from previewController(_:editingModeFor:)
    let delegateProxy = QLPreviewDelegateProxy()
            
    var documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
    
    /// A timer we use to update the QL controller
    /// Ideally, we would use callbacks or delegate methds, but couldn't
    /// find a satisfactory set to do the job. Instead we poll (like an animal)
    var quicklookControllerPollingTimer: Timer?
    
    /// Use this to track the preview controller created by UIDocumentInteractionController
    var quicklookController: QLPreviewController?
    
    /// File URL of the PDF we are editing
    var editURL: URL!
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        quicklookControllerPollingTimer?.invalidate()
    }
    
    @IBAction func showPopover(_ sender: Any?) {
        documentInteractionController.url = editURL
        documentInteractionController.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: button.bounds, in: button, animated: true)
        
        quicklookControllerPollingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [unowned self] timer in
            guard quicklookController == nil else {
                if quicklookController?.view.window == nil {
                    quicklookController = nil
                }
                return
            }
            if let ql = presentedViewController?.presentedViewController as? QLPreviewController, ql.view.window != nil {
                self.quicklookController = ql
                
                // Extra delay gives UI time to update
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) {
                    guard let ql = self.quicklookController else { return }
                    delegateProxy.originalDelegate = ql.delegate
                    ql.delegate = delegateProxy
                    ql.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}


class QLPreviewDelegateProxy: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
    
    weak var originalDelegate: QLPreviewControllerDelegate?

    /// All this work is just to return .updateContents here. Doing this makes it all work properly.
    /// Must be a bug in UIDocumentInteractionController
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        .updateContents
    }
    
}
```